# Is it bad practice to use std::shared_ptr with Qt containers when dealing with polymorphic classes?

Tags: c++, qt

Given that Qt containers require that their value type must be assignable, i.e. they must define a default constructor `X()` it is not possible to use `std::unique_ptr` with these containers and therefore if I thought that I could then use `std::shared_ptr` to have the desired polymorphic behavior of the container's contents.

Suppose I have the following scenario:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo();
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
  void foo();
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
  void foo();
};

QVector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec;
```

`QVector` stores possibly multiple instances of Derived1 and Derived2 mixed together and therefore I expect them to behave polymorphically, but also I would like these resources to be automatically managed.

So, is using shared_ptr to remedy this issue a bad practice and therefore I should exchange `QVector` for `std::vector` or is it acceptable?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` has a default constructor. It defaults to a `nullptr`. It doesn't have copy constructor, tho (still has move constructor).

Comment: Well, you decide whether this is acceptable to you. It would work, though `std::shared_ptr` introduces some overhead, unnecessary unless you do need shared ownership. Personally, I prefer `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`, moving away from Qt containers.

Comment: What's the reason for using Qt containers?

Comment: Using Qt containers mostly because I'm working inside Qt environment, following this line of thought -> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364404/when-writing-a-qt-application-is-good-practice-to-always-prefer-qt-function-impl